# Python bot (telebot) SyntaxError

Tags: python, bots, chatbot, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

when creating my own telegram bot I encountered an error

```
File "c:\Users\Кирилл\Desktop\python_bot — копия\main_part.py", line 7
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

part with code:

```
bot = TeleBot('ToKeN')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the **@** in `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])` is causing the error.

Remove the **@** and try again.

Answer (score 0):

after @... you should enter a method like this:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['hello'])
def handler(message):
    bot.reply_to(message,'hello!'
```